# How to inform browserify about extra dependencies within a transform module?

Tags: gulp, dependencies, browserify, through2

I created a browserify transform to transform `.pug` files to preparsed Ractive JSON objects. That operation requires to transform Pug files to HTML and then pass to the `Ractive.parse()` function.

What doesn't work after initial build is that when I change a relative Pug file, browserify doesn't recompile the parent file, so the change is not reflected to the bundle file. I'm using `watchify` to watch the file changes.

Consider the following `hello.js` file:

```js
var x = require('./index.pug')
...
```

and `index.pug` file:

```
b hello 
include ./a.pug
```

I can obtain `["/path/to/index.pug", "/path/to/a.pug"]` inside my transform function. How can I pass it to the browserify to invalidate its relevant cache whenever `index.pug` or `a.pug` has been changed within the transform function?

My transform function is as follows:

```js
var through2 = require('through2')

preparsePug = function(file, contents){
  // returns {
  //     dependencies (Array), 
  //     parsed (String)
  //  }
  ...
}

function isTemplate(file){
  return /.*\.(pug)$/.test(file);
}
exports.ractivePreparserify = function(file){
  var contents, write, flush;
  if (!isTemplate(file)) {
    return through();
  }
  contents = '';
  write = function(chunk, enc, next){
    contents += chunk.toString('utf-8');
    next();
  };
  flush = function(cb){
    try {
      var x = preparsePug(file, contents);
      this.push("module.exports = " + JSON.stringify(x.parsed));
      return cb();
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("Preparserify error: ", err);
      return this.emit('error', err);
    }
  };
  return through2.obj(write, flush);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the `watchify` module that does the actual caching between builds. `watchify` uses `browserify`'s internal cache under the hood, but still we send our signal to `watchify` to make browserify rebuild on dependency changes.

[As can be seen in the source code](https://github.com/browserify/watchify/blob/f79e59f8b46707c6102fd4d93ed940dcae937b15/index.js#L51-L53), a transform informs its browserify instance through watchify about its dependencies by `this.emit('file', dependency)` signal.

Above `ractivePreparserify` function should be:

```js
through = require('through');

ractivePreparserify = function(file){
  var contents, write, end;
  if (!isTemplate(file)) {
    return through();
  }
  contents = '';
  write = function(chunk){
    contents += chunk.toString('utf-8');
  };
  end = function(){
    var x, i$, x$, ref$, len$, e;
    try {
      var x = preparsePug(file, contents);
      for (var i = 0; i < x.dependencies.length; i++) {
        this.emit('file', x.dependencies[i]); // <----- Informs browserify about dependencies.
      }
      this.queue("module.exports = " + JSON.stringify(x.parsed));
    } catch (e$) {
      e = e$;
      console.error("Preparserify error: ", e);
      this.emit('error', e);
    }
    return this.queue(null);
  };
  return through(write, end);
};
```

In order this to work, browserify should be configured exactly as explained [here](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/fast-browserify-builds-with-watchify.md).